# Optimizing & fine tuning circuitikz diagrams

Tags: diagrams, circuitikz, draw, logic, circuits

Attached below is a pair of logic circuit diagrams that I've put together.

1. The first is the original, pieced together from SVGs and PDF annotation tools.
2. The second is my attempt to replicate the first, using LaTeX.

---

[image]

---

Pretty close, but the LaTeX version is lacking some of the original optimizations.

1. Input rails on the lefthand side don't reach the bottom.
2. Input labels (A,B) are staggered.
3. I/O labels (A,B,A'B') are oblique.
4. No splice indicators (little black balls).
5. No bold lines.

---

Here is the source, for anyone who cares to read it.

```
%%%%%INIT%%%%%
\documentclass[border=0.25cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

%%%%%HEAD%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}\draw

%%%%%OBJECTS%%%%%
(-0.00,-0.00)node[not port](not1){}
(-0.00,-1.25)node[not port](not2){}
(+2.75,-0.63)node[and port](and1){}

%%%%%INPUTS%%%%%
(not1.in)node[above left=1.50cm](a){$A$}
(not1.in)node[above left=0.50cm](b){$B$}
(a)|-(not1.in)
(b)|-(not2.in)
(not1.out)|-(and.in 1)
(not2.out)|-(and.in 2)

%%%%%OUTPUTS%%%%%
(and.out)node[right=0.63cm](a'b'){$A'B'$}
(and.out)--(a'b');

%%%%%TAIL%%%%%
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one version which draws the inputs separately. But really: Adjusting the `line width` is up to you (just pass the parameter to the `tikzpicture` if you want to adjust it).

The following code also corrects the errors that make your MWE non-working: using shapes with names that do not exist.

[image: circuit]

```
\documentclass[border=0.25cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

%%%%%HEAD%%%%%
\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (-2.5,-2) -- ++(0,3) node[above] (a) {\(A\)};
        \draw (-1.5,-2) -- ++(0,3) node[above] (b) {\(B\)};
        \draw 
        %%%%%OBJECTS%%%%%
        (0,0)node[not port](not1){}
        (0,-1.25)node[not port](not2){}
        (+2.75,-0.63)node[and port](and1){};

        %%%%%INPUTS%%%%%
        \draw[fill] (not1.in) -- (a |- not1.in) circle (1pt);
        \draw[fill] (not2.in) -- (b |- not2.in) circle (1pt);
        \draw (not1.out)|-(and1.in 1)
            (not2.out)|-(and1.in 2);

        %%%%%OUTPUTS%%%%%
        \draw (and1.out)node[right=0.63cm](a'b'){$A'B'$}
        (and1.out)--(a'b');

    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: how much differ coordinate `(-0.00,-0.00)` from simply `(0,0)`? :-) (zero is only zero. can not be negative or positive ...)

Comment: @Zarko There's no difference, that's still from the OP.

Comment: i was pretty sure that this is a case. however, you should remove this nonsense  :-)

Comment: It's not nonsense.

Comment: @TeXnician Your diagram is definitely an improvement. Thanks. What's an MWE? Also, I don't see any reference to `tikzpicture` in the code. Is that an additional package to import?

Comment: @tjtube263 Well `-0.00` is nonsense in the sense of being an unnecessary complex representation of he simple `0`. A MWE is a minimal working code example (i.e. some code snippet that actually compiles, your example is minimal, but not compilable). Regarding the tikzpicture: `circuitikz` is based on `tikz` which provides the `tikzpicture` environment. As you are already using TikZ syntax I thought you knew this details. But you could also simply say `\tikzset{line width=10pt}` (as an example) before the diagram.

Comment: It's not nonsense. It's not complex. It *is* non-essential. More importantly, it's neater, and increases readability when things line up nicely in a fixed width typeface. Likewise, the `+`, is non-essential, as are `%COMMENTS`, `50mm` is more concise than `0.50cm`, and so on. It only costs a few extra keystrokes here and there. Also, just FYI: I don't know much about LaTeX (I have about 5 days experience), but it's compilable; it compiles. It's the exact code I used to produce the image. Thanks again for the advice, I'll try it and let you know how I go.

Comment: @tjtube263 I don't want to argue about personal habits and I completely understand that everyone has his own preference for writing code, you do and so do I. But the code in your post (question) does not compile, because you call your shape "and1" and reference it as "and". It throws errors. Maybe your editor is configured to ignore them, but they are there, that's what I meant with the "working" part.

Comment: Great, I'm not interested in that either. I'm just saying, for the benefit of anyone reading this; it's not nonsense. Why? Because it makes sense. You're right though, I made a typo. I'll fix it.